# RoR - Global method for all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a little problem to understand where should I add an method that all the models can have access to it. I read other similar posts but it's not very clear where to add it. Some of them said about add it on "/lib" as a module an then include it in the model class (Already try this without luck). So what it's the best practice for add this?

I'm trying the following:

My module on: **/lib/search.rb**

```
module Search     
   def self.search(params,columns_search)
        srch = params[:search]

        if srch.blank?
          scoped
        else
          search= []
          #Add conditions for the search
          columns_search.map do |column|
            search << (sanitize_sql_for_conditions ["LOWER(CAST(#{column} as TEXT)) LIKE ?", "%#{srch.downcase}%"])
         end

          where("(#{conditions.join(" and ")})")

    end
end
```

On my model **cars.rb**

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Search

  attr_accessible :name

end
```

But i'm getting the following error on my console:

> Started GET "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-01 11:56:54 -0500
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Car::Search):
>   app/models/car.rb:2:in `'

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technique you mention seems like a reasonable approach - create a module (which will probably live in `/lib`) that defines the methods you want the models to have, and then include it in each model that needs it.

For instance, my current project has Images, Videos and Audios, all of which have certain method that should be available to them because they're all types of media.
I define a module in `lib/media.rb`:

```
module Media
  def self.included(base)
    # Associations etc. go here
    base.has_many :things
    base.mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    base.attr_accessible :image
    base.before_save :do_something
  end

  def do_something(argument=nil)
    #stuff
  end

end
```

And then in each of the media models, I include it:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Media

end
```

I can then call `Video.first.do_something`, just as though the method were defined in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now im trying again this way, but the problem is that i got the next error: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Cars::Search). I should add a new route or that should i miss?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a `RoutingError`, but if you're referring to `Cars::Search` somewhere, that is incorrect - you shouldn't need to, just call the methods defined in `Search` on a `Car` object.